# VIM search, ignore case for a single character

Tags: vim

Is there a way in vim to specify for a search pattern that a single character should be treated as case insensitive (This should be at most of the cases the first character in the word). For example, suppose I want to search the word `survey` but it can also appear as `Survey`.

Answer (score 7):

One way of doing it is by using a character collection, like

```
/[Ss]urvey
```

See `:help /collection`.